# SQL query for cross column unique values in single table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have a table with two columns and data as follows -

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| A       | B       |
+---------+---------+
| C       | D       |
+---------+---------+
| B       | A       |
+---------+---------+
| E       | F       |
+---------+---------+
| F       | E       |
+---------+---------+
```

My query output should return the following data -

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| A       | B       |
+---------+---------+
| C       | D       |
+---------+---------+
| E       | F       |
+---------+---------+
```

If we have two rows `row1` and `row2` where `row1.column1=row2.column2` and `row1.column2=row2.column1`, the output should contain either of the two rows `row1` or `row2`.

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Stop making it worse.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: If there's a row (J,H), is it alright to return (H,J) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 < col2
union all
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 > col2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col2 and t2.col2 = t.col1);
```

You might also want:

```
select distinct least(col1, col2) as col1, greatest(col1, col2) as col2
from t;
```

Note that in some cases, this could return pairs are not in the same order in the original data.